# Load libs from a different classloader in a web application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, classloader, axis

When a web application is loaded in `Tomcat` it is loaded by a specific classloader, right?
I assume that all libraries (under `WEB-INF\lib`) used by this web application are all loaded by this same classloader?
In this case, is there a way to load a library under a different classloader without any issues?
The reason I want to do this is because `Axis` uses some configuration properties that are bound to the classloader and would like to do requests with different properties thereby use a different classloader.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load classes programmatically at run time, you can use URLClassLoader, but it can be quite tricky to really get it right. You would do something like this:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] {
    /* URL to your axis jar */,
    /* other URLs you need */
};
URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<...> axisClass = classLoader.findClass(/* fully qualified name */);
```

Then you should be able to create a new instance of this class and use it.

**Edit:** Here is a more concrete example, albeit not using Axis because it would be too difficult to set up. I have create a JAR file that contains the following class:

```
public class Hello {
    public Hello(String config) {

    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I have copied this jar file to the source folder of my test project, so I can find it using `UrlClassloaderTest.class.getResource("hello.jar")`. In a web app, you should probably put it into WebContent/WEB-INF (or something similar) and use the method `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/hello.jar")` to find it. I can then access the Hello class using the URLClassLoader and reflection:

```
public class UrlClassloaderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL jarUrl = UrlClassloaderTest.class.getResource("hello.jar");
        URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarUrl }, UrlClassloaderTest.class.getClassLoader());

        Class helloClass = cl.loadClass("test.Hello");
        Constructor constructor = helloClass.getConstructor(String.class);
        Object helloObject = constructor.newInstance("some configuration");
        Method messageMethod = helloClass.getMethod("getMessage");
        String message = (String) messageMethod.invoke(helloObject);

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Note that I can not use Hello as a type here because it is not on the class path of the application, and so it is not known to the class loader of the class `UrlClassLoaderTest`!

Comment: Will there be an issue if I do this from inside `Tomcat` web-app?

Comment: I hope not :) You should be fine with this approach, you can even load the same jar multiple times this way. But note that classes loaded by different class loaders can not work together, so as I said, it can be tricky to get this completely right. It's also been quite a long time since I last had to fiddle with class loaders, so I can not guarantee anything...

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a more comprehensive code snippet as an example or a good reference example?

Comment: @Jim I have updated my post. Please accept the answer and/or upvote it if you think it is helpful now...

Comment: +1.So the `URLClassLoader` will load classes in a *different* classloader than the one of my web app? It will not be delegated to the *same* classloader that loaded my web app for instance?